# Custom fonts in Xcode 6 - Swift don't work

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, fonts

I'm trying to use a custom font in my Xcode iOS project I am working on. It is written in swift and I am planning to  change the font for the navigation bar. In the app delegate file I was trying to use this code: `UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName : Futura-Medium, size: 20,)]`
 but it has not worked.

The font is present in the p list and build phase as well as being targeted to the current project. Could anyone shed some light on how I may be able to get around this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following syntax:

```
 UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "Futura-Medium", size: 20)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()];
```

Comment: 's ok will give that a go as soon as possible. Thanks

Comment: let me know if you face any issue

Comment: Ilyas. That has done it! Thank you so much!!! It was just one of those little annoying things and it gets really frustrating when you can't figure out why it won't work. I've up voted :)

Comment: Tried to up vote it but it wouldn't let me because my rep is less than 15

Answer (score 0):

Don't you mean:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name:"Futura-Medium", size: 20)!];
```

Comment: I tried that and it caused the app to crash for some reason. Will give it another go and report back though. Thanks anyway :)